# error in evaluating the argument 'drv' in selecting a method for function 'dbConnect': could not find function "MySQL"

Tags: r, rmysql, dbconnect

I am getting an error message " error in evaluating the argument 'drv' in selecting a method for function 'dbConnect': could not find function "MySQL""

Here is the part of the code:

```
library(DBI) 
conn <- dbConnect( drv = RMySQL::MySQL(), dbname = "xxx", host = "xxx", username = "xxx", password = "new_password") 
dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM tech LIMIT 1;") 
dbDisconnect(conn)
```

Comment: try to load the `RMySQL` library explicitly

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a script in an interactive session, call `library(RMySQL)` to load the package.

If you get this error while developing a package, add `RMySQL` to the Imports field of your `DESCRIPTION` file.  You can do that with `usethis::use_package("RMySQL")`.